# vba macro innertext of html page access

Tags: html, vba, innertext

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim objIe As InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim xobj As Variant
    Dim links As Variant
    Dim link As String
    Dim lnk As Variant
    Dim rc As Integer
    Set objIe = New InternetExplorerMedium
    objIe.Visible = True
    objIe.navigate "C:\Users\SOURABH\Desktop\test.html"
    Do While objIe.Busy And Not objIe.readyState = 4
        Application.StatusBar = "Loading.."
        DoEvents
    Loop
    MsgBox objIe.document.body.innerHTML
    Set xobj = objIe.document.getElementByTagName("myDiv")
    Set xobj = xobj.getElementsByClassName("myTable").Item(0)
    Set xobj = xobj.getElementsByClassName("data")(0)
    For Each lnk In links
        MsgBox "lnk got accessed"
        If lnk.className = "myTable" Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 1).Value = lnk(0).innerText
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox xobj.innerText
    Set xobj = Nothing

    objIe.Quit
    Set objIe = Nothing
End Sub
```

And my HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">    
<table class="myTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Text1:</td>
                <td class="data"><strong>0.51</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text2:</td>
                <td class="data"><strong>2199</strong></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I can see the innertext using the MsgBox command but while getting the classname in the innertext I get an error:

> object doesn't support this property in set xobj = objIe.document.getElementByTagName("myDiv") line

Please help me to find a way to get the innertext of class "data"

Comment: I'm curious why are you using vba to get access to the html dom?

Comment: Actually I was trying to do some automation to get notified with new mail alert without manually signing in mail server. Please do suggest better options to access html source code. Your suggestions are always appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to access it by TAGNAME, which in MyDiv's case, is DIV.

I think what you want is:

```
Set xobj = objIe.document.getElementById("myDiv")
```

**EDIT** Additional Question 
I tried doing this, but I am on a Mac :( If I were to GUESS, I would say you should try something like:

```
For Each obj In xobj.getElementsByClassName("data") 
    MsgBox obj 
Next
```

Also use the debugger to break on the MsgBox, you can see what is in the object

Comment: Hey can you help me to get the string "Text1:" and "Text2:" as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have made an attempt for you